# Scrapy Override file_path from FilesPipeline

Tags: python, scrapy

I want to modify the output folder of the downloaded files and based on [source code of files pipeline](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/pipelines/files.py), `file_path` can be override, i tried the below code but it seems i didn't work. Btw, I'm new on python - scrapy.

**pipelines.py**

```
from scrapy.pipelines.files import FilesPipeline

class secFilesPipeline(FilesPipeline):
    def file_path(self, request, response=None, info=None):
    ## start of deprecation warning block (can be removed in the future)
    def _warn():
        from scrapy.exceptions import ScrapyDeprecationWarning
        import warnings
        warnings.warn('FilesPipeline.file_key(url) method is deprecated, please use '
                      'file_path(request, response=None, info=None) instead',
                      category=ScrapyDeprecationWarning, stacklevel=1)

    # check if called from file_key with url as first argument
    if not isinstance(request, Request):
        _warn()
        url = request
    else:
        url = request.url

    # detect if file_key() method has been overridden
    if not hasattr(self.file_key, '_base'):
        _warn()
        return self.file_key(url)
    ## end of deprecation warning block

    media_guid = hashlib.sha1(to_bytes(url)).hexdigest()  # change to request.url after deprecation
    media_ext = os.path.splitext(url)[1]  # change to request.url after deprecation
    return 'test/%s%s' % (media_guid, media_ext)
```

**settings.py**

```
ITEM_PIPELINES = {
'myproject.pipelines.secFilesPipeline': 2,
'scrapy.pipelines.files.FilesPipeline': 1,
}

FILES_STORE = '/home/joseph/pdf'
```

**Expected output:** Ex. FILES_STORE + Month + filename.pdf = /home/joseph/pdf/September/filename.pdf

Any idea? Thank you.

Comment: Did you manage to find a way to set this from inside the pipeline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you should do is to override `file_path` method. So you are on the right track. But there seem to be some indentation problems in your code example. I also had problems with this because when an error occured, even with `DEBUG` setting, `scrapy` silently ignored the file saving. So start simple where you only return a simple string first from `file_path` for testing.

See [the files pipeline file](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/1.5/scrapy/pipelines/files.py)...

```
def file_path(self, request, response=None, info=None):
    url = request.url
    media_guid = hashlib.sha1(to_bytes(url)).hexdigest()  # change to request.url after deprecation
    media_ext = os.path.splitext(url)[1]  # change to request.url after deprecation
    return 'full/%s%s' % (media_guid, media_ext)
```

What you can do is to define a base path for `FILES_STORE` such as `/home/joseph/pdf` then change the `file_path` method so it returns something like

```
    return '%s/%s%s' % (month_text, media_guid, media_ext)
```

You have to have necessary date functions to set `month_text` obviously.

Answer (score 1):

Setting `FILES_STORE` value in your `settings.py` should suffice as per [documentation](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/media-pipeline.html#enabling-your-media-pipeline).

Comment: the default output path is `FILES_STORE` + `full` , Im planning to modify the filename. Ex. `FILES_STORE` + `Month` + `filename.pdf` = `/home/joseph/pdf/September/filename.pdf`

Comment: @Joseph I was answering the question: *I want to modify the **output folder***...

Comment: Based on my code, I already did that and try to edit the `full` path folder and also base on the title of this. I will edit my question to clarify more.

Comment: @Tomáš Linhart, he wants to have a dynamic directory structure which he can set from inside the pipeline programmatically.